# Local vs global Sobolev space

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let
\begin{equation}
H_{\text{loc}}^{2}(\mathbb{R}^d)=\{u:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}\;|\;u\in H^{2}(V)\text{ for all }V\subset\subset \mathbb{R}^d\}.
\end{equation}
I was wondering if it is true that
\begin{equation*}
L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\cap H^s_\mathrm{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)=H^s(\mathbb{R}^d).
\end{equation*}
Intuitively, I was thinking that the local Sobolev regularity should `cure' the local singularities by making them $H^s$, while the decay of derivatives could be controlled by the $L^2$ decay. However, I was not able to come up with a proof or with a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take a radially symmetric $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^d)$, fix $k\in \mathbb R$ and let 
$$
f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \phi(n^k x-n^{k+1}), $$
where $a_n\in \ell^2$. This function is in $H^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(\mathbb R^d)$, since it reduces, locally, to a finite sum. Moreover, 
$$
\lVert f\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}^2=C_1\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-kd} |a_n|^2.$$
On the other hand, since
$$
\partial_r f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^ka_n \phi'(n^kx-n^{k+1}), $$ 
we have that 
$$
\lVert\partial_r f\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}^2=C_2\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{2k-kd} \lvert a_n\rvert^2. $$
Choosing, say, $|a_n|^2=n^{kd-\alpha}$ with 
$$
kd-\alpha <-1\qquad 2k-kd-\alpha \ge -1$$
produces a counterexample.

---

The idea is taking an infinite series of functions, with disjoint supports that stretch more and more. The $L^2$ norm of the function and the one of the derivative behave differently under this stretching, and this can be used to make the derivative blow up.

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. The same reasoning works with all $H^s$, for $s>0$. Instead of $\partial_r$, use the multiplier $D^s$, defined as $D^sf:=\widehat{|\xi|^s\hat{f}}$. This is homogeneous of degree $s$, while $\partial_r$ is homogeneous of degree $1$.